# How to compile PECL extension win32service for PHP7.0 on Windows

Tags: php, c, pecl

I tried to compile the pecl extension `win32service` from https://pecl.php.net/package/win32service

On the pecl page above are in the time of writing only versions for PHP5.5 and PHP5.6 available. So I tried to compile it on my own. Since PHP7.0 is building fine in my environment I received some linker errors.

```
Creating library C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc14\x64\php-7.0.14-src\x64\Release_TS\php_win32service.lib and object C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc14\x64\php-7.0.14-src\x64\Release_TS\php_win32service.exp
win32service.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Z_TYPE_PP referenced in function svc_thread_proc
win32service.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Z_STRVAL_PP referenced in function svc_thread_proc
win32service.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Z_STRLEN_PP referenced in function svc_thread_proc
win32service.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Z_LVAL_PP referenced in function svc_thread_proc
C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc14\x64\php-7.0.14-src\x64\Release_TS\php_win32service.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
```

Used configuration (Windows 7, x64, TS, VC14, PHP7.0.14):

> configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-win32service=shared

How to build that extension or how to fix the code to link fine?

Comment: The last version of win32service was released (beta) in 2011. Talks about PHP7 started in 2014-2015. It seems like there is no support for that currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a note from the maintainer pointing in some direction of where the root cause is. Thanks a lot Richard.

Extensions have to be adapted from PHP (5.x.x) to PHPNG (7.x.x).
The internals have changed and the macros (e.g. Z_TYPE_PP) are no more.

The documentation https://wiki.php.net/internals/engine/objects says:

> The type of zval may be read using Z_TYPE() or Z_TYPE_P() macros, type flags using Z_TYPE_FLAGS() or Z_TYPE_FLAGS_P(), the combination of type and flags – Z_TYPE_INFO() or Z_TYPE_INFO_P(). PHPNG doesn't work with pointers to pointers to zval and it doesn't provide macros with _PP() suffix anymore (like Z_TYPE_PP).

So this means the code of the extension has to be kind of refactored/rewritten since the macros are gone as you can see in the PHP code itself:

PHP5.6: http://lxr.php.net/source/xref/PHP-5.6/Zend/zend_operators.h#491

PHP7.0: http://lxr.php.net/source/xref/PHP-7.0/Zend/zend_types.h#337

**Update:**
Since my question there has been a lot of work being done in that extension. There have been several working realeases and even dll's being uploaded to the pecl page:
https://pecl.php.net/package/win32service

Answer (score 1):

I'm build php_win32service for PHP-7.0 and PHP-7.1:
https://github.com/fawno/pecl-system-win32service/releases
https://github.com/alpha/win32service/releases

Update:
macintoshplus is working for updating the extensión in https://github.com/InExtenso/win32service
He needs helps for become mantainer of package:
https://github.com/InExtenso/win32service/issues/4